# Slow consumer impact on a topic partition

Tags: apache-kafka

Let there be a single Kafka topic with just a single partition configured with an infinite retention policy. Let there be two consumers, `Fast` and `Slow`.

The `Fast` consumer processes the message as they appear and has almost no lag.

The `Slow` consumer tends to have a significant lag e.g. two days worth of messages. `Slow` will sometimes catch up to `Fast` but this happens rarely, there is usually a significant lag.

Will this setup, with two different consumer speeds in the same partition, cause negative side effects on a Kafka broker? Could there be an increased I/O cost to retrieve older messages for `Slow` consumer from the disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lagging consumer won't be able to read data from OS cache. Therefore there will be I/O cost for slow consumers. On the other hand, after your slow consumer started to read message, kafka will make sequential I/O to cache messages. If the latency is not too much, consumer can find the next message in the cache.

Comment: Any chance there is a performance test somewhere showing the impact of consumer latency on disk cache?

Comment: No, i didn't test it myself. I think message processing statistics would be meaningful in that test. For example; if some messages takes too much time and others are processed quickly, then disk I/O won't be too much.